# Using #ifdef on token-pasted macros?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I know there is already a similar post to mine ([C++ `ifdef` with concatenation of macros values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109448/c-ifdef-with-concatenation-of-macros-values)) but the post is pretty old and the solution provided does not work for me, because I cannot set the define I want to check. So I hope someone can help me.

The problem is that I want to make an ifdef of a concatenation of two a define with a fixed text.

Imagine the following code

```
#define ENABLE_MODULE_1

enum Modultype
{
    MODULE_1,
    MODULE_2
};

#define MODULE MODULE_1


int main()
{
    #ifdef ENABLE_ ## MODULE
    printf("NAME defined");
    #else
    printf("NAME not defined");
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

So I basically want to check if `ENABLE_MODULE_1` is defined based on the `MODULE` define.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: please provide link to the old post. And you cannot use preprocessor in the preprocessor.

Comment: The `##` operator is specific to the replacement lists of function-like macros.  You cannot use it (directly) in conditional-inclusion directives.

Comment: You still can't do it - why not ask a question about the failing solution, instead?

Comment: Is this the question you were referring to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109448/c-ifdef-with-concatenation-of-macros-values

Comment: And can you please explain why the solution in the question linked by @templatetypedef does not work for you?

Comment: The solution in the question provided by @templatetypedef might work for you. Please try it.

Comment: The problem with the solution provided is that I cannot set the `base_dll` define to 1 because it is given from a configuration file which is out of my hands. Otherwise it would work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Preprocessor macros only expand once, and only when not in another preprocessor statement. Along with that, concatenations can only be used within a `#define` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do precisely what you want because `#ifdef` operates on an identifier, not a preprocessor expression, and the `##` operator can only be used in the replacement text of a macro definition.

If you are willing to define `ENABLE_MODULE_1` (if defined at all) with a non-zero constant as its replacement text, you can achieve something similar to what you want as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define XENABLED(x)         ENABLE_ ## x
#define ENABLED(x)          XENABLED(x)

#define XSTR(x)             #x
#define STR(x)              XSTR(x)

#define ENABLE_MODULE_1     1   /* enabled */
#define ENABLE_MODULE_3     0   /* not enabled */

#define MODULE              MODULE_1
#define OTHER               MODULE_2
#define ANOTHER             MODULE_3

int main(void)
{
#if ENABLED(MODULE)
    printf("%s enabled\n", STR(MODULE));
#else
    printf("%s not enabled\n", STR(MODULE));
#endif
#if ENABLED(OTHER)
    printf("%s enabled\n", STR(OTHER));
#else
    printf("%s not enabled\n", STR(OTHER));
#endif
#if ENABLED(ANOTHER)
    printf("%s enabled\n", STR(ANOTHER));
#else
    printf("%s not enabled\n", STR(ANOTHER));
#endif
#if ENABLED(UNDEFINED)
    printf("%s enabled\n", STR(UNDEFINED));
#else
    printf("%s not enabled\n", STR(UNDEFINED));
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

The above program produces the following output:

```
MODULE_1 enabled
MODULE_2 not enabled
MODULE_3 not enabled
UNDEFINED not enabled
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunatly I cannot set the `ENABLE_MODULE_1` as it is given in a configuration file which I do not have access to. I was therefore looking for a general soluation, so that I do not have to check manually for each ENABLE, but apparently this cannot be done. Many thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: @EmbedEngineer I've added a variant using `defined()` that might help you.

Comment: @IanAbbott Note that the solution using `defined(...)` invokes undefined behaviour as far as the standard is concerned: “If the token `defined` is generated as a result of [macro replacement in the controlling expression of `#if` or `#elif`], the behavior is undefined” (C89 6.8.1, C99 and C11 6.10.1). Yes, in standard C you can invoke undefined behaviour _during compilation_; yes, that’s stupid.

Comment: @AlexShpilkin Thanks for the information. I'll remove that part.